# Replace several lines of commands with a single variable in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I know I have been asking a lot of questions but I'm still learning tcl and I haven't found anything that similar to this issue anywhere so far. Is it at all possible to replace a set f commands in tcl with one variable `function0` for example?

I want to be able to replace the following code;

```
set f [listFromFile $path1]
set f [lsort -unique $f]
set f [lsearch -all -inline $f "test_*"]
set f [regsub -all {,} $f "" ]
set len [llength $f]
set cnt 0
```

with a variable `function0` because this same code appears numerous times within the script. I should mention it appears both in a `proc` and not in a `proc`

The above code relates to similar script as

```
while {$cnt < $len} {
    puts [lindex $f $cnt]
    incr cnt
    after 25; #not needed, but for viewing purposes
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want to define a proc called `function0` containing the repeated code.  But you also seem to be aware of `proc`, so I'm confused what you really want.

Comment: I want to not have to write the code out numerous times within my script. Preferably write it once at the beginning and call to it when needed to clean it up and if I need to change it I only need to change it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are for storing values. To hide away (encapsulate) some lines of code you need a command procedure, which you define using the `proc` command.

You wanted to hide away the following lines

```
set f [listFromFile $path1]
set f [lsort -unique $f]
set f [lsearch -all -inline $f "test_*"]
set f [regsub -all {,} $f "" ]
set len [llength $f]
set cnt 0
```

to be able to just invoke for instance `function0 $path1` and have all those calculations made in one fell swoop. Further, you wanted to use the result of calling the procedure in code like this:

```
while {$cnt < $len} {
    puts [lindex $f $cnt]
    # ...
```

Which means you want `function0` to produce three different values, stored in `cnt`, `len`, and `f`. There are several ways to have a command procedure return multiple values, but the cleanest solution here is to make it return a single value; the list that you want to print. The value in `len` can be calculated from that list with a single command, and the initialization of `cnt` is better performed outside the command procedure. What you get is this:

```
proc function0 path {
    set f [listFromFile $path]
    set f [lsort -unique $f]
    set f [lsearch -all -inline $f test_*]
    set f [regsub -all , $f {}]
    return $f
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
set f [function0 $path1]
set len [llength $f]
set cnt 0
while {$cnt < $len} {
    puts [lindex $f $cnt]
    incr cnt
    after 25; #not needed, but for viewing purposes
}
```

or like this:

```
set f [function0 $path1]
set len [llength $f]
for {set cnt 0} {$cnt < $len} {incr cnt} {
    puts [lindex $f $cnt]
    after 25; #not needed, but for viewing purposes
}
```

or like this:

```
set f [function0 $path1]
foreach item $f {
    puts $item
    after 25; #not needed, but for viewing purposes
}
```

This is why I didn't bother to create a procedure returning three values: you only really needed one.

---

glenn jackman makes a very good point (or two points, actually) in another answer about the use of `regsub`. For completeness, I will repeat it here.

Tcl is a bit confusing because it usually allows string operations (like string substitution) on data structures that aren't formally strings. This makes the language very powerful and expressive, but also means that newbies do not always get the kick in the shins that a regular type system would give them.

In this case you created a list structure inside `listFromFile` by reading a string from a file and then using `split` on it. From that point on it's a list and you should only perform list operations on it. If you wanted to take out all commas in your data you should either perform that operation on each item in the list, or else perform the operation inside `listFromFile`, *before* splitting the text.

String operations on lists will work, but sometimes the result will be garbled, so mixing them should be avoided. The other good point was that in this case `string map` is preferable to `regsub`, if nothing else it makes the code a bit clearer.

Documentation: [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: Would this work if it is used to set up other code? cause every time I use it, it is to relate to some following code

Comment: @LiamP: I'm not 100% sure what you mean here. A command procedure usually plays well with other code (it is, after all, quite crucial to how Tcl works). I suggest you try using it (take a backup copy of your code first). The only way to tell for sure if it works is to try it.

Comment: I tried it but im not quite sure how to get that to work with
    while {$cnt < $len} {
        puts [lindex $f $cnt]
        incr cnt
        after 25
    }

Comment: It is working now! Thank you sorry for all the confusion

Comment: @LiamP: no prob, you have to start somewhere. You should have seen the questions I posted to comp.lang.tcl fifteen years ago :)

Answer (score 1):

(more of a comment than an answer, but I want the formatting)

One thing to be aware of: $f holds a *list*, then you use the string command `regsub` on it, then you treat the result of `regsub` as a list again.

Use list commands with list values. I'd replace the regsub command with

```
set f [lmap elem $f {string map {"," ""} $elem} ]
```

---

for Tcl version 8.5 or earlier, you could do this:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $f]} {incr i} {
    lset f $i [string map {, ""} [lindex $f $i]]
}
```

Comment: Good point. I considered mentioning it, but deemed it a bit too advanced for the asker's current level of understanding.

Comment: I tried the example you gave but it comes up with `invalid command name "lmap"`

Comment: You must have a version of Tcl older than 8.6